# ggplot2: geom_area() blank gaps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use geom_area to show the percentage of cohort's contribution over time.
Below is a reproducible dataset, apologize as it requires some external libraries.

```
library(BTYDplus)
library(tidyverse)
custFirstTxn <- BTYDplus::groceryElog %>% group_by(cust) %>% arrange(cust, date)  %>%
  filter(row_number()==1) 
custFirstTxn$cohort <- tsibble::yearmonth(custFirstTxn$date)

custFirstTxn %>% group_by(cohort) %>% summarise(n()) %>% ungroup()

custFirstTxn <- custFirstTxn %>% ungroup() %>% dplyr::select(-date)
```

```
BTYDplus::groceryElog %>% left_join(custFirstTxn) %>%
mutate(yearweek = tsibble::yearweek(date)) %>% group_by(cohort, yearweek) %>%
  summarise(txn_count = n()) %>% 
  group_by(yearweek) %>% 
  mutate(txn_per = (txn_count / sum(txn_count))*100) %>% arrange(yearweek) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=yearweek, y=txn_per, fill=factor(cohort))) + geom_area(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_classic() + labs(fill = "Cohort")
```

[image]

```
BTYDplus::groceryElog %>% left_join(custFirstTxn) %>%
  mutate(yearmonth = tsibble::yearmonth(date)) %>% group_by(cohort, yearmonth) %>%
  summarise(txn_count = n()) %>% 
  group_by(yearmonth) %>% 
  mutate(txn_per = (txn_count / sum(txn_count))*100) %>% arrange(yearmonth) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=yearmonth, y=txn_per, fill=factor(cohort))) + geom_area(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_classic() + labs(fill = "Cohort")
```

[image]

Notice that the charts have 'gaps' (white areas) in the early dates.
How can I ensure that the white areas are effectively flattened?
For example below, we don't see the white areas anymore

[image]

How can I also easily switch between percentage and raw count?

Comment: you might have to impute those dates with your y-axis being 0?

Comment: You mean use complete() ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant answer I have, but it works in principle

```
# create all combinations of cohort and yearmonth
master <- BTYDplus::groceryElog %>% left_join(custFirstTxn) %>%
  mutate(yearmonth = tsibble::yearmonth(date)) %>% dplyr::select(cohort, yearmonth) %>% distinct() %>%
  expand(cohort, yearmonth)

# calculate the cohort yearmonth percentage
slave <- BTYDplus::groceryElog %>% left_join(custFirstTxn) %>%
  mutate(yearmonth = tsibble::yearmonth(date)) %>% group_by(cohort, yearmonth) %>%
  summarise(txn_count = n()) %>% 
  group_by(yearmonth) %>% 
  mutate(txn_per = (txn_count / sum(txn_count))*100) %>% arrange(yearmonth) %>% dplyr::select(-txn_count)

# join to the master table
master_slave <- master %>% left_join(slave) 
# set those combinations with no amount to 0
master_slave$txn_per[is.na(master_slave$txn_per)] <- 0

# plot
master_slave %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=yearmonth, y=txn_per, fill=factor(cohort))) + geom_area(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_classic() + labs(fill = "Cohort")
```

[image]